# Strange interaction between h5py, subprocess and mpirun

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, mpi, h5py

Appears that importing *h5py* prevents running *mpi* tasks with *subprocess*.

Consider following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#import h5py
import subprocess

result=subprocess.run(['mpirun','-np','2','uptime'],shell=False)

print(result.returncode)
```

With first line commented, output looks like:

```
 15:44:04 up 5 days,  6:34,  4 users,  load average: 29,16, 29,89, 25,09
 15:44:04 up 5 days,  6:34,  4 users,  load average: 29,16, 29,89, 25,09
0
```

If I uncomment the first line then output looks like:

```
1
```

Nothing was executed, no error messages was printed, return code is 1.

Everything was tested on Ubuntu 19.10. 
On Ubuntu 18.04 there is no such problem.

Probably because h5py is linked with serial hdf5 in 18.04 and with parallel hdf on 19.04

Is it a bug or feature? 
What will be the correct way to launch an mpi task in such a situation?

Comment: `h5py` depends on `mpi4py`, which means `MPI_Init_thread()` is called **before** `mpirun`. For internal reasons, an Open MPI application cannot invoke `mpirun`. One option is to rebuilt `h5py` so it does not depend on `mpi4py`, and an other option is to use `MPI_Comm_spawn()` instead of `subprocess.run()`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, The problem is not connected with subprocess.
Same behavior with os.system, os.execvp,...

Look like simple importing of this version of *h5py* initializes MPI environment for the process.
As a result any child process receives a lot of environment variables related to *openmpi*.

You can see some of these variables with following code:

```
import h5py
import os
os.system('env | grep PMIX')
```

Output may look like:

```
PMIX_RANK=0
PMIX_NAMESPACE=4066967553
PMIX_GDS_MODULE=ds21,ds12,hash
PMIX_SYSTEM_TMPDIR=/tmp
PMIX_SERVER_URI2=4066967552.0;tcp4://127.0.0.1:39583
PMIX_SERVER_URI3=4066967552.0;tcp4://127.0.0.1:39583
PMIX_BFROP_BUFFER_TYPE=PMIX_BFROP_BUFFER_NON_DESC
...
```

With such environment variables *mpirun* silently exit with error code 1.

Strange, but these environment variables are not seen in *os.environ*. 
However this gives a workaround for the problem: 
just explicitly pass *os.environ* to child process. 
Either using third argument of *os.execvpe* or passing *env=os.environ* to *subprocess.Popen*.

So the corrected program from the question may look like as:

```
import h5py
import subprocess
import os

result=subprocess.run(['mpirun','-np','2','uptime'], env=os.environ, shell=False)

print(result.returncode)
```

For me the workaround is sufficient.